# switch Program `PID` in VLC via command line

Tags: udp, vlc, mpeg2-ts

I have got a `MPEGTS` file that contains multi programs `PID's` recorded from `UDP` stream.

How to switch Playback->Program in `VLC` via command line.

Comment: @aergistal thanks ... can you post it as an answer ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option is `--program <service_id>`. For full usage information you can do `vlc -H`.